# CF7 refill issue

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

So basically I have Contact form 7 installed on wordpress. I have this coming up on gtmetrix which is annoying and costing me the site speed.

```
wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/2562/refill
```

Is there anyway I can avoid this issue? I don't even have captcha on the forms..

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 7):

adding javascript

```
wpcf7.cached = 0;
```

to the end of the footer solved the issue

Comment: Hi Tnx For solved.
Tiis Work for me nad i set this in my them **footer.php**.


* `<script>wpcf7.cached = 0;</script>`

Comment: Hi Milad, how can i Access to Object wpcf7 in footer.php

Comment: @salaheddineOuar maybe you don't need to access the wpcf7 object but you can use the relevant event handlers provided by the wpcf7 api. See documentation here https://contactform7.com/dom-events/